# Memory RAM address of a variable in Lua

Tags: c++, variables, lua, memory-address

How to access in C++, the memory address of a variable declared in the language Lua???

in other words (example in written Lua):

**X = 10**

How to access the memory address of the variable X, which was declared on the Lua?

**address = (&X)** ?????????

Help me please!!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Is `lua_getfield` not enough?

Comment: I need to know the memory address of a variable that was declared in Lua

Comment: Lua variables do not have addresses. Perhaps you can explain why you think you need it, so that we can help you actually do what it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

You don't,  you ask the Lua API for the value of the variable, or set it.

use :-

- lua_getfield
- lua_setfield

refer...

http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html

for a description and examples.