# How to get memory address in lua?

Tags: variables, memory, lua

Have checked the lua documentation and haven't found the function that ouput specific value from the memory address. Is there a function in lua that allows to output the memory address value?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memory RAM address of a variable in Lua](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8980317/memory-ram-address-of-a-variable-in-lua)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: Which address do you want to pass to this function?

Answer (score 2):

While this doesn't work with `nil`, `boolean` or `number` types, you can use `string.format`:

```lua
("%p"):format(my_object)
```

to get a string representation of the memory address of the object behind the variable `my_object` in vanilla Lua.

Answer (score 1):

Or if it is not a string you do

```
blabla = tostring(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with LuaJIT, you can create this function yourself (works only on x86-32):

```
read_memory_dword = require"ffi".cast("__fastcall uint32_t (*)(uint32_t)",
                                      "\x8B\x01\xC3") -- mov EAX,[ECX] / ret
YourValue = read_memory_dword(YourAddress)
```

Comment: You don't need to write assembly for this... just do: `require"ffi".cast("int*", YourAddress)[0]`